# Fetch response is Promise pending but already fullfilled

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

I'm using the fetch module on Javascript to get a JSON object from my server, but the return value is a *Promise {<pending>}* that has two attributes.

One is *[[PromiseState]]: "fullfilled"*

The other is *[[PromiseResult]]: Array(1)*, which has my JSON response as first item in the array.

How can I retrieve my JSON object in some way? I think the best way would be "completing" the Promise but I'm using *async/await* with the fetch module; I already tried switching to *then/catch* but the result of the "then" part is still the same pending Promise.

The *async/await* code is the following:

```
(async function () {
  const result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/check", {
    method: "GET",
  });
  
  console.log(result.json());
})();
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You got me, I meant JSON, period. Sorry

Comment: The `.json` call is what returns a Promise, you need to await *it* instead of the double awaits around the `fetch`

Comment: @Andreas shoot, I forgot to delete that first await, that was a thing I was trying to solve the problem, obviously without success. Sorry for the second time

Comment: @CertainPerformance that was it, thanks!